# one nodejs/express app only works on localhost, but not using IP address, another nodejs/express app works just fine?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, localhost

I have a super simple Hello World app that I got to run on `myipaddress:3000` instead of just `localhost:3000` by doing:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    http = require("http");


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("home.ejs");
  });


app.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0", function() {
   console.log('Server running on port 3000');
 });
```

but i have another, more involved node.js/express app that also uses mongoDB/mongoose where when I change the `app.listen` to include `"0.0.0.0"`, it still only runs on `localhost:3000`. I'm not sure what could be causing this, maybe something to do with mongoDB? that's the only real difference between that apps that I can think of that would make a difference. I'm not running them both on port 3000 at the same time. I also tested the Hello World with a different port and it worked fine, but the other app did not.

Does anyone know what else could be the issue here? Let me know if you need to see any other code.

Comment: just `app.listen(3000)` will suffice to listen on all interfaces, inc `myipaddress` if its not connectable from outside then its most likly routing setup, myipaddress could mean LAN ip like 192. or a WAN one from your ISP, both may need setting up, simply setting to listen all interfaces wont poke though firewalls etc

Comment: @LawrenceCherone but wouldn't the fact that the hello world app works on the ip address prove that there aren't any firewall issues? it seems like it's a problem with the other app...maybe because it has other aspects to it like mongodb and mongoose, etc

Comment: if express cant listen on the port or bind to an address it will error out, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

As I know `0.0.0.0` is given as a host to access from the outside interface. And If you don't specify the host while calling `app.listen()` The server will run on all available interface ie. on `0.0.0.0` but you can bind the IP address like

```
  app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1', function(){
   console.log('Server running on port 3000');
});
```